# CUDA Block-wide Parallel Primitives

Tags: c++, cuda

Are there any built-in CUDA kernel functions that are equivalent to OpenCL 2.0 work_group_* functions? I'm specifically looking for work_group_scan_exclusive_add and work_group_reduce_add. My naive implementations of these operations do not perform as well as OpenCL's built-in functions, and I expect that an implementation using __shfl could be used to speed things up with CUDA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CUDA itself does not provide this functionality.

The [CUB library](https://github.com/NVlabs/cub) was built with this purpose in mind.

The block-level primitives are summarized [here](http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/group___block_module.html).

This [page](http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/classcub_1_1_block_reduce.html) has reference code for implementation of a block reduce.